# Dockerize React-Node app communication between containers failure

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose, containers

I'm trying to dockerize a react-node app. I have created a docker compose file. I am trying to send a simple get request from react to node (with axios) but react container fails to resolve the ip of node container. As I read online, react should be able to resolve the IP of node by the name of the container. So the idea is to pass the url http://backend:3001/api to the react container through an environment variable (REACT_APP_API_URL) and use it to send the requests to the server but it doesn't.

Here is my docker compose:

```
version: '2.13'
services:
  frontend:
    depends_on:
      - backend
    build: ./client
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    expose:
      - 3000
    environment:
      - REACT_APP_API_URL=http://backend:3001/api
    volumes:
      - ./client:/app

  backend:
      depends_on:
        - database
      build: ./server
      ports:
        - 3001:3001
      expose:
        - 3001
      environment: 
        - DB_URL=mongodb://database/cloud-app
      volumes:
        - ./server:/app
      command: ["nodemon", "index.js"]

  database:
      image: mongo:6.0
      ports: 
        - 27018:27017
      volumes:
        - ebook-volume:/data/db

volumes:
  ebook-volume:
```

Server:

```
app.get("/api/books", async (req, res) => {
  const books = [
    {
      id: 5,
      title: "book1",
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      title: "book2",
    },
  ];

  res.status(200).send(books);
});
```

Client

```
  const API_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL;
  const apiEndpoint = API_URL + "/books";

  const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
 
    async function getAllBooks() {
      const { data } = await axios.get(apiEndpoint);
      setBooks(data);
    }

    getAllBooks();
  }, []);
```

And that's what I get on the console in the browser:

```
GET http://backend:3001/api/books net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED          xhr.js:247
```

Meanwhile if I use http://localhost:3001/api instead of http://backend:3001/api it works fine. I guess that's because of the ports 3001:3001 and 3000:3000 inside docker compose. So the flow goes from react container to host machine and then from host machine to node container. Am I getting this right? If that's the case, is that a good architecture? Shouldn't the containers be able to communicate without involving the host machine?

Comment: Consider that React apps run in browser which runs on the host

Comment: So in case I deploy this application on cloud where should react send the requests? At the public IP of the VM that I got from the cloud?

Comment: Yes. An alternative is to have the front-end server act as a proxy for the API, then you don't have to worry about CORS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey your container can talk to each other without the need of the host, you can put them inside the same network or link them.
Also when you test in your browser, the code is not executed in the container but inside your browser, that mean it's normal to have to put `localhost`. To solve this you can add an entry inside your `/etc/hosts` if you are running linux.

Comment: So in case I deploy this application on cloud where should react send the requests? At the public IP of the VM that I got from the cloud?

Comment: You can but the best practice is to use a domain name.
You should change url depending on if you are in developnent or production.